# Automatically set minimum size of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, minimum-size

I have a subclass of `JPanel`, and I want it to, as soon as its parent frame is `pack()`ed, to set its minimum size to its new preferred size. I've tried using a `ComponentAdapter`, but `JPanel`s are by default visible; if I `setVisible(false)` at the beginning of the constructor, the `JFrame` won't make it visible again. If I use `SwingUtilities`'s method to get the window root, it will return `null` because it's in a constructor.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *"What's the best way to do this?"*  Your stated goal sounds like nonsense.  Care to elaborate to the point where it does not?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I don't understand why it's "nonsense." Are you saying that this isn't a good practice, or that it's incredibly easy and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: In 'answer' to your 2 questions, I'll simply advise.. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Maybe then I can figure what you're talking about.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, you're right; I forgot to do that. Thanks for helping anyway, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a subclass of JPanel, and I want it to, as soon as its parent frame is pack()ed, to set its minimum size to its new preferred size.

If you know the preferred/minimum size before the pack, set it then.

Comment: No, I don't; it uses a `GridBagLayout` with two rows of `JLabel`s, and then a dynamically-sized pane. Is it possible to calculate the spacing and everything on a layout manager?

Comment: You (generally) don't need to; `pack()` accounts for each component's preferred size.

Answer (score 1):

> to set its minimum size to its new preferred size

Certainly possible, but whether it is useful ... . You can override the `getMininumSize()` method to return `super.getPreferredSize();`